# 2-Cocycles and Automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, geometry

hopefully a short question, which can be answered by someone who is more into that topic than I am.

Suppose we have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ valued 2-cocycle $\epsilon$ defined on a root lattice $\Phi$ of a simply laced Lie algebra, i.e.
$\epsilon : \Phi \times \Phi \mapsto \{\pm 1\}$ with $\epsilon(a,b) \epsilon(a+b,c) = \epsilon(b,c) \epsilon(a, b+c)$.

In addition let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $\Phi$, $\alpha \in $ Aut$(\Phi)$. Can we say something about the transformation of the cocycle if we act with an inner/outer automorphism on its arguments, such that we can write
$\epsilon(\alpha(a),\alpha(b)) = \epsilon(a,b) \cdot f(a,b)$ for some appropriate function $f$ ?

Comment: First, it's a little idiot, but "yes you can", you just have to define $f$ as the quotient (of course the question is rather "what can we say about $f$"). For inner automorphisms, the induced automorphism of the cohomology group is the identity, so you can take $f$ a coboundary (it can probably be made explicit but I don't know a formula on top of my head). For outer automorphisms it will probably be more complicated, because in general the cohomology class will be changed.

Comment: Divide the equality you want by $\epsilon(a,b)$.